# SQL Query not returning Null values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using the query below to get the **USD** values, but when **Unit_price** is null then it has to return null values, and I am not getting null values. Please advise me where I am going wrong. Thanks!

DB: Oracle 11g

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT data_raw_id,
       f.ndc_cd,
       date_of_service,
       quantity_dispensed,
       p.unit_price,
       NVL((SELECT f.quantity_dispensed * pc.prc_amt
             FROM llpricing_lkup pc
            WHERE pc.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd
              AND f.date_of_service BETWEEN pc.strt_dt AND pc.end_dt),
           f.quantity_dispensed * p.unit_price) usd
  FROM fact_data f
  JOIN product p
    ON f.ndc_Cd = p.ndc_Cd
 WHERE data_Raw_id in (44214229, 44214183, 41084896, 41244850, 41374409, 41501126, 41501107);
```

the output for the above query is below..

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix would be to enclose the `usd` expression in a `case` expression that specifies your business rule:

```
select data_raw_id
     , f.ndc_cd
     , date_of_service
     , quantity_dispensed
     , p.unit_price
     , case when p.unit_price is not null then
           nvl
           (
             ( select f.quantity_dispensed * pc.prc_amt
               from   llpricing_lkup pc
               where  pc.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd
               and    f.date_of_service between pc.strt_dt and pc.end_dt
             )
           , f.quantity_dispensed * p.unit_price
           )
       end as usd
from   fact_data f
       join  product p
             on  p.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd
where  data_raw_id in (44214229, 44214183, 41084896, 41244850, 41374409, 41501126, 41501107);
```

Looking at that, though, it seems you could simplify things by merging your scalar subquery into the main query as an outer join:

```
select data_raw_id
     , f.ndc_cd
     , date_of_service
     , quantity_dispensed
     , p.unit_price
     , case
           when p.unit_price is not null then
               f.quantity_dispensed * nvl(pc.prc_amt,p.unit_price)
       end as usd
from   fact_data f
       join  product p
             on  p.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd
       left join llpricing_lkup pc
             on  pc.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd
             and f.date_of_service between pc.strt_dt and pc.end_dt
where  data_raw_id in (44214229, 44214183, 41084896, 41244850, 41374409, 41501126, 41501107);
```

The *'return value y or z defending on whether x is null'* logic can also be expressed using

[`nvl2(some_value, value_if_not_null, value_if_null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL2.html)

so in your query I make that:

```
nvl2(p.unit_price, f.quantity_dispensed * nvl(pc.prc_amt,p.unit_price), null) as usd
```

but I always find `nvl2` less readable than the equivalent `case` expression.

As for where you are going wrong, the `llpricing_lkup` scalar subquery fetches values regardless of `product.unit_price`, so as long as some quantity was dispensed and a pricing lookup row is defined covering the date of service then you will get a value.

Comment: Thank you very much William for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

NVL function in oracle returns the first not null value. Your NVL function -

```
NVL ((SELECT f.quantity_dispensed * pc.prc_amt
                        FROM llpricing_lkup pc
                       WHERE pc.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd 
                         AND f.date_of_service BETWEEN pc.strt_dt
                                                   AND pc.end_dt)
                   , f.quantity_dispensed * p.unit_price) usd
```

Is using some calculation from llpricing_lkup table and must be returning some values. Hence you are not getting any null value. You have to remove the sub-query if you want to get the null in usd column.

Comment: Thank you ankit for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `NVL()` function accepts two arguments. If `e1` evaluates to null, then `NVL()` function returns `e2`. If `e1` evaluates to non-null, the `NVL()` function returns `e1`.

**Syntax::**

```
NVL(e1, e2)
```

So in your query Select statement inside the **nvl** function is not null that is why it returned **USD** column data . Please use below query at the place of `NVL ()` function.

```
NVL (f.quantity_dispensed * p.unit_price,(SELECT f.quantity_dispensed * pc.prc_amt
                        FROM llpricing_lkup pc
                       WHERE pc.ndc_cd = f.ndc_cd 
                         AND f.date_of_service BETWEEN pc.strt_dt
                                                   AND pc.end_dt)) usd
```

Comment: Thank you Ajeet for your help.